# Adding sample results to a list while looping

Tags: random

Attempting to build a random walk simulation that counts how many times a level is reached within a given number of steps.  The amount is then passed into a list.  My issue is that I would like to run multiple samples in a row, adding the individual results to the list.  Right now the code produces a list with ten items, but they are all the same.

ie:

```
"sample" = 10
"steps" = 1000
```

the code runs 10, one thousand step random walk sessions, each one a sampling, and produces a list with 10 unique results of how many times the level of 100 was reached during each run.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
import random
sample = input('Samples : ')
steps = input('Steps : ')
s = 0
a = 0
x = 0
list1 = []
list2 = []
while s < int(sample):
    s = s + 1
    while a < int(steps):
        a = a + 1
        r = random.randint(-1,1)
        x = x + r
        if x == 100:
            list1.append(x)
        y = len(list1)
    list2.append(y)
print(list2)
```

---

Comment: Please identify the language you are using.

Comment: Language = Python 3.4

Comment: When you say "they are all the same," what value appears 10 times?

Comment: The count.  Seems like it is looping the appending part.  If it is set to loop (sample) ten times the resulting list would be something like [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,].  I have tried many different indentation set ups and moved the list around in the code, but none seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to reset `a` and `list1` at the start of each sample, no?  That is, move their initializations to just before the start of the inner `while` loop.  Since you don't reset `a`, the inner loop never gets entered after the first sample is done, so `y` never changes any more, so you keep getting the count from the first sample.

And the only time you append to `list1` is when `x` reaches 100, which is unlikely to happen at all given a limit of 1000 steps.  (Why do you need a list, since you only care about the count, and know you'll be appending 100 each time?)

Comment: 1,000 step reference is used mainly just for example.  The list would be a list of the separate results of each run. 1st run = 2 times, second = 8 times, 3rd run equals 5 times would look like this: [2,8,5].

Comment: @SRQ: That's how `list2` is used; I was talking about `list1`.

Comment: list1 is just a list that gives me a way to count how many times 100 was reached. Then that count value is appended into list2 showing the count as a result for that particular sample...then I need it to loop, count again and append the next result to the end of list2.  Building the list until the requested number of samples is complete.